# When I swap keys using SetWindowsHookEx WH_KEYBOARD_LL, why does my program get into a cycle of too many keyboard input events?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, keyboard-hook

I am trying to write a program for Windows system that swaps the <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> keys, i.e. when I press the <kbd>A</kbd> key, `B` gets typed, and vice versa.

To do so, I first map the <kbd>A</kbd> key to behave like the <kbd>B</kbd> key. Here is the code I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

HHOOK hook;

LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *p = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
    DWORD newVkCode;
    INPUT inputs[1];
    UINT ret;

    char wParamStr[16];
    char vkStr[16] = "";

    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "KEYDOWN");
    else if (wParam == WM_KEYUP)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "KEYUP");
    else if (wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "SYSKEYDOWN");
    else if (wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "SYSKEYUP");
    else
        strcpy(wParamStr, "UNKNOWN");

    if (p->vkCode == 10)
        strcpy(vkStr, "<LF>");
    else if (p->vkCode == 13)
        strcpy(vkStr, "<CR>");
    else
        vkStr[0] = p->vkCode;

    printf("%d - %s - %lu (%s) - %d - %lu\n",
           nCode, wParamStr, p->vkCode, vkStr, p->scanCode, p->time);

    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wScan = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.time = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    if (wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) {
        inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    }

    if (p->vkCode == 'A') {
        inputs[0].ki.wVk = 'B';
        ret = SendInput(1, inputs, sizeof (INPUT));
        return 1;
    }
    /*
    else if (p->vkCode == 'B') {
        inputs[0].ki.wVk = 'A';
        ret = SendInput(1, inputs, sizeof (INPUT));
        return 1;
    }
    */

    return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MSG messages;

    hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHook, NULL, 0);
    if (hook == NULL) {
        printf("Error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Waiting for messages ...\n");
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works as expected. I first compile this code with the following commands.

```
"%vs80comntools%\vsvars32.bat"
cl /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0401 /EHsc foo.c /link user32.lib
```

Now, I run the program. I go to another program, say, Notepad, and press the <kbd>A</kbd> key and `B` gets typed. I see the following output from the above program when this happens.

```
C:\foo>foo.exe
Waiting for messages ...
0 - KEYUP - 13 (<CR>) - 28 - 874702239
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 30 - 874703752
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874703752
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 30 - 874703877
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874703877
```

Now, I move on to the next step of mapping the <kbd>B</kbd> key to behave like the <kbd>A</kbd> key. To do this, I simply uncomment the five lines of code that is commented above, compile it and run it again.

This also behaves as expected. When I press the <kbd>A</kbd> key, `B` gets typed, and when I press the <kbd>B</kbd> key, `A` gets typed. However, when I check the output of the program, I see too many events.

Here is the output of the program, when I press the <kbd>A</kbd> key exactly once.

```
C:\foo>foo.exe
Waiting for messages ...
0 - KEYUP - 13 (<CR>) - 28 - 874746621
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 30 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749008
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 30 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874749101
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874749101
```

After this, when I press the <kbd>B</kbd> exactly once, I see the following output.

```
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 48 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824590
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 48 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 0 - 874824637
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 874824637
```

Why are there so many events here? I am guessing this happens because when I press the <kbd>A</kbd> key,

- The `keyboardHook` function is called with the keyboard input event for the <kbd>A</kbd> key press.
- It processes the keyboard input event and sends a keyboard input event for the <kbd>B</kbd> key.
- The `keyboardHook` function is called again for the <kbd>B</kbd> key.
- It processes it and sends an event for the <kbd>A</kbd> now.
- The whole cycle repeats.
- After 10 such cycles, the Windows system probably interferes and stops the cycle.

The above six point explanation is pure imagination. I have a few questions about this.

1. Can we explain why so many events are generated using an official documentation from Microsoft? If an official documentation is not available, can we prove the reason behind the generation of so many events by writing another program or performing some experiment?
2. If the events are generated indeed due to repetition of the same cycle (i.e. consuming `A`, generating `B`, consuming `B`, generating `A`, repeat), then how does it stop automatically after 10 cycles? Can this be also explained using an official documentation, another program or any experiment?

By the way, I know how to work around this. For the fake key events sent using the `SendInput` function in the `keyboardHook` function, the hardware scan code is set to `0` in the following statement.

```
    inputs[0].ki.wScan = 0;
```

So I can use this fact to ignore events sent by the `keyboardHook` function in the `keyboardHook` function by modifying the key mapping part of the code as follows.

```
    if (p->vkCode == 'A' && p->scanCode != 0) {
        inputs[0].ki.wVk = 'B';
        ret = SendInput(1, inputs, sizeof (INPUT));
        return 1;
    }
    else if (p->vkCode == 'B' && p->scanCode != 0) {
        inputs[0].ki.wVk = 'A';
        ret = SendInput(1, inputs, sizeof (INPUT));
        return 1;
    }
```

Now when I press the <kbd>A</kbd> key, I get the familiar output.

```
C:\foo>foo.exe
Waiting for messages ...
0 - KEYUP - 13 (<CR>) - 28 - 875183112
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 30 - 875186310
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 875186310
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 30 - 875186388
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 875186388
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: So, is your question why the loop doesn't continue indefinitely? Because you seem to have demonstrated very neatly that the fake input event is indeed passed to your hook, causing theoretically unbounded recursion.

Comment: @IMSoP I have two questions: (1) Can we explain why so many events are generated using an official documentation from Microsoft? If an official documentation is not available, can we prove the reason behind the generation of so many events by writing another program or performing some experiment? (2) If the events are generated indeed due to repetition of the same cycle (i.e. consuming A, generating B, consuming B, generating A, repeat), then how does it stop automatically after 10 cycles? Can this be also explained using an official documentation, another program or any experiment?

Comment: Well, question 1 I think you've already demonstrated using your program that sets the scan code to zero on one iteration, and reads it out on the next; that's pretty certain proof that each time you generate a fake input event, the event you create is being sent to your hook. You could perhaps modify it to set the scan code to 1,2,3,4,etc if you're still not convinced.

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you for your comments. I agree my first question is answered by my program and the output. The program sets the hardware scan code in "fake input" events to zero and the output shows that the program is receiving these "fake input" events as well. The fourth field in every row of the output displays the hardware scan code and we can see events with scan code 0 there. I have also tried setting the hardware scan code to other numbers like 11, 12, etc. and I see those numbers also appearing in the output. So I am convinced about this.

Comment: Apps may need correct scan codes to operate correctly. Instead, check the injected flag to detect recursion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the suggestion of Raymond Chen in the comments to the question, here is a complete program that swaps <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> in the right way, i.e. by checking the injected flag of the low-level keyboard input event. In other words, I perform the following test to decide whether to consume a low-level keyboard input event and replace it with another.

```
(p->flags & LLKHF_INJECTED) == 0
```

Here is the complete program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

HHOOK hook;

LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *p = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
    DWORD newVkCode;
    INPUT inputs[1];
    UINT ret;

    char wParamStr[16];
    char vkStr[16] = "";

    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "KEYDOWN");
    else if (wParam == WM_KEYUP)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "KEYUP");
    else if (wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "SYSKEYDOWN");
    else if (wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "SYSKEYUP");
    else
        strcpy(wParamStr, "UNKNOWN");

    if (p->vkCode == 10)
        strcpy(vkStr, "<LF>");
    else if (p->vkCode == 13)
        strcpy(vkStr, "<CR>");
    else
        vkStr[0] = p->vkCode;

    printf("%d - %s - %lu (%s) - %d - %lu\n",
           nCode, wParamStr, p->vkCode, vkStr, p->scanCode, p->time);

    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wScan = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.time = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    if (wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) {
        inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    }

    if (p->vkCode == 'A' && (p->flags & LLKHF_INJECTED) == 0) {
        inputs[0].ki.wVk = 'B';
        ret = SendInput(1, inputs, sizeof (INPUT));
        return 1;
    } else if (p->vkCode == 'B' && (p->flags & LLKHF_INJECTED) == 0) {
        inputs[0].ki.wVk = 'A';
        ret = SendInput(1, inputs, sizeof (INPUT));
        return 1;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MSG messages;

    hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHook, NULL, 0);
    if (hook == NULL) {
        printf("Error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Waiting for messages ...\n");
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This can be compiled as follows.

```
"%vs80comntools%\vsvars32.bat"
cl /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0401 foo.c /link user32.lib
```

Now when I run this program, go to another program, say, Notepad, and press the <kbd>A</kbd> key, `B` gets typed. I see the following output from the above program when this happens.

```
C:\lab\foo>foo.exe
Waiting for messages ...
0 - KEYUP - 13 (<CR>) - 28 - 588708476
0 - KEYDOWN - 65 (A) - 30 - 588711206
0 - KEYDOWN - 66 (B) - 0 - 588711206
0 - KEYUP - 65 (A) - 30 - 588711284
0 - KEYUP - 66 (B) - 0 - 588711284
```