# How to change keyboard behaviour?

Tags: c++, winapi

OS: Windows 10
Programming language: c++
Interface: winapi

My goal is to create callback function to WH_KEYBOARD_LL. In this function I want to change behaviour key "B". Of course I know that I have to use

```
wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN
PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
int code = p->vkCode;
```

And check is the key is "B".

Next I want to change my "B" button in "A" button, so in my OS, where the hook will be run I will have two "A" keys: normal and that old "B".

I would like that old "B" ( new "A" ) will be like "A", so when I press "B" + "CTRL" I would like to select all text. When I press "B" I want to see letter "A" in notepad. When I press "B" in somewhere I want to get "A" behaviour.

How looks like winapi normal key behaviour code when system get message about key down?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I swap keys using SetWindowsHookEx WH\_KEYBOARD\_LL, why does my program get into a cycle of too many keyboard input events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303878/when-i-swap-keys-using-setwindowshookex-wh-keyboard-ll-why-does-my-program-get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the key from inside a low-level hook.  But, what you can do is have your hook *simulate* your own input events for <kbd>A</kbd> using [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) when it receives input events for <kbd>B</kbd>, and then have the hook return a non-zero value instead of calling [`CallNextHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-callnexthookex) to block the input events for <kbd>B</kbd>.

Have a look at [When I swap keys using SetWindowsHookEx WH_KEYBOARD_LL, why does my program get into a cycle of too many keyboard input events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303878/) for an example.